# Scrapy can't return reference because it takes up 2 lines

Tags: xpath, scrapy

The first line of the table is easy to scrape because the title "P/E Ratio (TTM)" is written neatly on one line. The other lines of the table however, I can't seem to scrape because "P/E High - Last 5 Yrs." takes up 2 lines and I have no idea how to reference it. Same goes for "P/E Low - Last 5 Yrs."

```
<tr class="stripe">
        <td>P/E Ratio (TTM)</td>
        <td class="data">11.39</td>
        <td class="data">87.22</td>
        <td class="data">19.22</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>
           P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.</td>
        <td class="data">34.48</td>
        <td class="data">114.12</td>
        <td class="data">24.22</td>
    </tr>
<tr class="stripe">
        <td>              
          P/E Low - Last 5 Yrs.</td>
        <td class="data">10.54</td>
        <td class="data">12.02</td>
        <td class="data">11.39</td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to return the numbers in this table. What I have so far that works is:

```
response.xpath("//td[./preceding-sibling::td[1]='P/E Ratio (TTM)']//text()").extract()
response.xpath("//td[./preceding-sibling::td[2]='P/E Ratio (TTM)']//text()").extract()
response.xpath("//td[./preceding-sibling::td[3]='P/E Ratio (TTM)']//text()").extract()
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something very obvious here. Here is the link to the site: https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/AB

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xpath` like shown below to access the `<td>` under `<tr>` having text like

> P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.

as mentioned in question

```
//tr[td[normalize-space()='P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.']]/td[2]
//tr[td[normalize-space()='P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.']]/td[3]
//tr[td[normalize-space()='P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.']]/td[4]
```

`normalize-space()` trims space at both ends of the text so you can match it even if it is spread in multiple lines

Comment: I used 
response.xpath("//tr[td[normalize-space()='P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.']]/td[2]/text()").extract()
and got exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough. You've been a huge help!. Have a great weekend. 10/10

Comment: Yes and you can change the xpath to what i've mentioned in the answer to solve your problem